# Repeating sound playing every 10 minutes in background

Tags: swift

I want to play a sound every 10 mins even when the app is in the background, is it possible? I tried few things with info.plist, but did not work.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player: AVAudioPlayer?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 20.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.playSound), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: .mixWithOthers)
            print("Playback OK")
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("Session is Active")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }


    @objc func playSound() {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sound", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

            guard let player = player else { return }

            player.play()

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }


}
```

I would really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to enable the Audio, AirPlay and Picture in Picture Background Mode in Capabilities. Otherwise you can't play Audio in Background.

[image: Enable Audio, AirPlay and Picture in Picture Background Mode]

Unfortunately this only works as long as your App plays audio. As soon as your App is in background and the latest audio ends, the app terminates. So your method with a timer won't work.

The only method that works (but probably Apple won't accept the app for the AppStore), is that you play another completely silent audio file when the app is in the background (e.g. with an AVQueuePlayer) and every ten minutes you set the queue to your sound.

I used this method a while ago and it worked quite well. I even saw an App in the AppStore which used this method but I don't know how they came through App Review.